# Db2 Driver issue on ibm Integration bus?

Tags: java, db2, esb, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

Senario

> ```
> M1: Ubuntu 16.04.3 broker installed for deployment  ( INSTALLED ON DOCKER)
> M2: Centos 7.5.1804 db2 installed  ( INSTALLED ON DOCKER)
> M3: windows 8.1 machine with iib toolkit installed for development of flows
> ```

I have successfully created datasource on M3 ( windows machine containing iib toolkit ) now when I deploy on remote broker installed on M1(IIB toolkit) configured as remote node on M3(machine) inside iib toolkit .

I developed a flow using M3(machine) having 'database retrieve node' for performing select operation and found exception :

Exception Code:

```
<exceptionList> 
<RecoverableException> 
<File>/build/S1000_slot1/S1000_P/src/DataFlowEngine/MessageServices/ImbDataFlowNode.cpp</File> 
<Line>1251</Line> 
<Function>ImbDataFlowNode::createExceptionList</Function> 
<Type>ComIbmDatabaseRetrieveNode</Type> 
<Name>gen/TestDB#FCMComposite_1_8.gen/operation1_Request_Response#FCMComposite_1_1</Name> 
<Label>gen.TestDB.operation1_Request_Response.Database Retrieve</Label> 
<Catalog>BIPmsgs</Catalog> 
<Severity>3</Severity> 
<Number>2230</Number> 
<Text>Node throwing exception</Text> 
<Insert> 
<Type>14</Type> 
<Text>gen.TestDB.operation1_Request_Response.Database Retrieve</Text> 
</Insert> 
<DatabaseException> 
<File>JDBCCommon.java</File> 
<Line>566</Line> 
<Function>JDBCConnection::createConnection</Function> 
<Type/> 
<Name/> 
<Label/> 
<Catalog>BIPmsgs</Catalog> 
<Severity>3</Severity> 
<Number>6232</Number> 
<Text>Problem encountered obtaining JDBC connection</Text> 
<Insert> 
<Type>5</Type> 
<Text>Broker 'BAHLESBUATDOCKER'; Execution Group 'default'; Message Flow 'gen.TestDB'; Node 'operation1_Request_Response.Database Retrieve'; Node Type 'DatabaseRetrieve</Text> 
</Insert> 
<Insert> 
<Type>5</Type> 
<Text>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</Text> 
</Insert> 
<Insert> 
<Type>5</Type> 
**

> <Text>  error message: No suitable driver, SQLState value: 08001

**, stack trace: [com.ibm.broker.jdbcnodes.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:236) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbcnodes.JDBCConnection.getNodeConnection(JDBCConnection.java:149) 
com.ibm.broker.jdbcnodes.DatabaseRetrieveNode.evaluate(DatabaseRetrieveNode.java:407) 
com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.evaluate(MbNode.java:1452)]</Text> 
</Insert> 
</DatabaseException> 
</RecoverableException> 
</exceptionList>
```

Am i missing some jar or something need to be deployed over M1 or M2 ?

Comment: the broker needs to communicate with Db2 via jdbc. Although Db2 can be co-located with IIB it can also be configured to work with remote databases (e.g. in another container). To work with a remote Db2 database, the machine running IIB needs to have a Db2-client installed and iib needs to be configured appropriately to use that database(mqsisetdbparms) , and the database needs the relevant tables etc.  Refer to documentation for IIB.  This is *CONFIGURATION* and not programming.

Comment: cant we use this odbc cli driver for db2 install inside M1(machine) url is bellow for db2 driver [link](https://iwm.dhe.ibm.com/sdfdl/v2/regs2/smkane/IDSOC/Xa.2/Xb.bL-snMrfTDzxAbcDvel2ksd2xvMwKo0FveFMRThIVUY/Xc.ibm_data_server_driver_for_odbc_cli_linuxx64_v11.1.tar.gz/Xd./Xf.LPr.D1vk/Xg.10247640/Xi.swg-idsoc97/XY.regsrvs/XZ.or6VFLfp25_zhHrDq_zEqh7O9s0/ibm_data_server_driver_for_odbc_cli_linuxx64_v11.1.tar.gz) instead of installing complete db2 client.

Comment: Yes to connect with odbc/cli you just need a Db2 driver, do not need the full Db2 driver, so choose the smallest footprint supported Db2 driver that fits your needs

Comment: Now which thing we should download (please provide link) and configure (steps ) inside M1 machine. Kindly provide detailed answer. Thanks for such a nice support.

Comment: You cannot use ODBC driver for a JDBC connection. The DatabaseRetrieve node needs a type 4 JDBC driver. 1. You need to put a type 4 JDBC driver for DB2 on M1. 2. You need to create a configurable service on IIB on your M1 that specifies the DB connection details. 3. Use mqsisetdbparms to provide credentials to IIB for connecting to the DB. 4. Configure the DatabaseRetrieve node (Data source name) to use the created configurable service.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ah61310_.htm

Comment: As per my current understanding 
1. We need to provide jdbc driver jars in M1 [DONE]
2. We need to created a object in service JDBCProviders in my senario I am using db2 default [DONE]
3. We need to set parameters accordingly in db2 via command line or GUI interface ( via brocker webconsole accessible on 4414 port) . [DONE]
4. In flow we just need to refer step 3 db2 in datasource name. [ DONE]
Now data source is working but now . 
1.  Is it possible to hide user name & password from url or provide them dynamically then what should be the process.